# How to pass mouse move x and y of type double from host to a virtual machine in Qemu

Tags: c++, qemu

I have written a virtual `USB` device and have registered it in `Qemu` object model.
Once I receive a relative mouse move using library `libinput` I need to give relative `x` and `y`, buttons state, and vertical with horizontal scroll shift to `Qemu`. But `libinput` gives me double values for the relative move.

I did not find the source file where `Qemu` actually parses the bytes I pass from host to the virtual machine.

Can I actually give `double` values of `x` and `y` for the relative mouse move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, see include/ui/input.h

```
void qemu_input_queue_rel(QemuConsole *src, InputAxis axis, int value);
```